# How get an ArrayList return from the WebService

Tags: java, android

I have a WebService with a method returns an ArrayList with two values, and in Android I need to save in another ArrayList but when i do the .add(), gives me an ArrayList with one value [string, string].

Here is the code form the WebService method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "mostarNombre")
public ArrayList<String> mostarNombre(@WebParam(name = "id") int id) {
    String nomb = "";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xxx:xxx", xxxx, xxxx);

        String query = "select * from ejemplo where id = 1";
        Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            nomb = rs.getString("nombre");
            String ids = rs.getString("id");

            list.add(nomb);
            list.add(ids);
        } 

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return list;
}
```

And here is the code from my method in Android:

```
 public void consultar(View v){
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String resultadoFINAL;

        //Creacion de la Solicitud
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD2);

        //Creacion del Envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.dotNet = true;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        //Creacion del transporte
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        // Paso de parámetro
        PropertyInfo numeroEmp = new PropertyInfo();
        numeroEmp.setName("numero");
        request.addProperty(numeroEmp);

        //Llamada
        transporte.call(SOAPACTION2, sobre);

        //Resultado
        Object resultado = (Object) sobre.getResponse();
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add(resultado.toString());
        String a = lista.get(0);

        tvConsulta.setText(lista.get(0));
        tvEj.setText(lista.get(1));

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I do the lista.get(0) I get one value like [string, string]. How I can solve this ?

**EDIT:**

The final solution is casting to Vector:

```
Vector lista = (Vector) sobre.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lista.add(resultado.toString());

first you have to understand what toString do.
toString method return the refrence of object by default if you not override it.That why its store only one value that is reference of array list return from webservice.

do this

1- if its return array list then assign it in arraylist directly.
eg 
    `ArrayList<String> lista=sobre.getResponse();`

2- just iterate over result and add in list.there are a no of way to iterate over list.i use simple for each loop.

```
for(String value:resultdo){
lista.add(value);
}
```

Comment: I can't do `ArrayList<String> lista = sobre.getResponse();` Incompatible types, required ArrayList, found Object

Comment: As i see your method is returning ArrayList<String> 
      @WebMethod(operationName = "mostarNombre")
       public ArrayList<String> mostarNombre(@WebParam(name = "id") int 
       id) {}               try to cast it explicitly using ArrayList<String> lista = 
        (ArrayList<String>)sobre.getResponse();

Comment: Thaaaanks for the idea of cast, but the final solution was `Vector lista = 
(Vector)sobre.getResponse();`